# Adding iPad XIB/VIEW to a "View Based Application" in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, xib

I've created a **View Based Application** in **XCode4** and trying to do the code and UI design according to the way Apple have intended it to be.

So I designed the UI in the **AppNameViewController.xib** and it works fine; now I want to enable it as a **UNIVERSAL** application that runs on iPad as well. I changed the **App-Target>>Summary>>Devices** from **iPhone** to **Universal** and miraculously XCode had automatically created **MainWindow-iPad.xib** (Apple, very nice...), but since I designed the application first screen on the **AppNameViewController.xib** and not on the **MainWindow.xib** when I run the app on **iPad Simulator** I get this ugly screen where my UI objects size and location is distorted (their size is still set for iPhone so they are all crumbled on the left-top corner of the screen).

In my previous app I used the code appearing below to distinct between the **AppNameViewControllerForIPHONE.xib** and the **AppNameViewControllerForIPAD.xib**; It was done from the **AppDelegate.m** file, but in the new XCode **View Based Application** template the AppDelegate doesn't go through **initWithNibName** method at all.

Code I used on XCode 3 that cannot be used on XCode 4:

---

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

viewController = [[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppViewControllerIPAD" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

}

else {

viewController = [[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppViewControllerIPHONE" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

}
```

---

Long question... still, anyone had any idea how it should be done here? Where should I design the iPad UI or is there a way to easily transform the iPhone xib to an iPad one?

Comment: I'm confused - above the code, it sounds like you need help figuring out which nib to load. Below the code, it sounds like you're asking how do you design the iPad UI. Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: RyanR, I have created a View Based Application and selected "iPhone" in Device Family. I designed the UI on the xib file. Now I want to add an iPad xib, but I don't know how to direct the app to it.

Comment: You'll have to [migrate the application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html) to a Universal App.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the new naming scheme (idiom in Apple-speak) specified for [Universal Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24) for the `NSMainNibFile` key in your info.plist. For example, if you set your NSMainNibFile to be "MainWindow-iPhone", the xib for ipad would be "MainWindow-iPad".

The same naming convention should hold for the views in a view based application (I can't test right now, installing new xcode).