# What is the Difference between Window Based Application and View Based Application?

Tags: ios, templates, view, window

I'm working on a new application that will hold a "main view" leading to another view when clicking on buttons in the main view.
I'm not sure which template to choose as a starting point: Window Based Application or View Based Application.

Can someone explain the differences between them?
What should I take into consideration when selecting between the two?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368774/cocoa-touch-which-to-use-window-template-or-view-template

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the reference, but I would appreciate a more specified answer (if someone is willing of course...) since in the original question/answer it's not very clear in which cases one should select which of the 2 different templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, I would use the View Based Application.  The difference between window and view is that the window template does not create a view controller class and related user interface file (.xib).  It just gives you a blank window.  In iOS there can only be 1 window, but multiple views can be presented on that window.

The View based template does everything that the window based template does PLUS it creates a view controller class and that class's xib file.  In addition, it adds that first view controller to your window.  In iOS, when you want to show another view, you'll almost certainly want another view controller class.  View controller classes can add additional views on top of themselves with ease.

Since the Window template gives you 0 to start with and the View template gives you 1 to start with and you'll eventually need 2 for your two views, it'll be less work for you to start with the View template.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, while we are at it - can you tell why when creating a View Based Application there is no "Universal" option in the Device Family field while when creating a Window Based Application there is one?

Comment: It's just the way the templates are set up.  You can still convert a View based template into a universal app by selecting the project (top left corner in Xcode) select the target, and in the Summary tab, set Devices to "Universal".  It'll ask you if you want to add a new XiB file.  Just answer yes, and now you have a universal app from a View Based Template.

Comment: OK, I did that, but it adds "mainWindow-iPad.xib" file. I designed the UI on the "ViewController.xib" (and the application is going there without me adding any code); I have no idea how to direct the application to the iPad.xib. should I direct it to the "mainWindow-iPad.xib" file or should I create a "ViewController-iPad.xib" and somehow direct the code there in case (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the original question.  I'd advice you to start a new question or look at pre-existing questions like this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497246/adding-ipad-xib-view-to-a-view-based-application-in-ios-4

Comment: I did publish another question but didn't get an answer for it and thought you may know... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522810/adding-ipad-xib-to-a-view-based-application-template-application-in-xcode-4