# Adding iPad XIB to a View Based Application Template Application in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, xcode4, xib

I've created a **View Based Application** in **XCode4**; when creating the application I selected iPhone as the **Device Family**:

[image]

The application was created with the following files:

[image]

I designed the UI on the **TestushViewController.xib** file and without adding any code in the **Delegate** files, the application is uploading immediately to the **TestushViewController.xib** view and I'm very happy about it.

Now I want to add an **iPad xib**. How do I do that?

(I knew how to do it in XCode 3, but I used some code in the Delegate file, and now if I try to use the same code it doesn't work because the template default implementation works differently - Apple uses **@class TestushViewController** and s**elf.window.rootViewController = self.viewController** and it goes directly to the iPhone.xib. I don't know how to go around it without changing the entire thing to the way it was done in XCode3)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to structure your code in a similar way that the Window Template does.  The file structure that template uses when the "Universal" option is ticked at creation is:

```
App Name/
  AppNameAppDelegate
  iPhone/
    AppNameAppDelegate_iPhone
    MainWindow_iPhone.xib
  iPad/
    AppNameAppDelegate_iPad
    MainWindow_iPad.xib
```

The iPhone and iPad AppDelegates are simply subclasses of the AppNameAppDelegate

```
@interface YourAppNameAppDelegate_iPhone : YourAppNameAppDelegate {}
```

In your target summary you can set what .xib file is initially loaded for each device.  It is called the "Main Interface" and has a pulldown menu.

Quite frankly, if you're wanting to do a universal app (iPhone + iPad) it's probably easier just to start with the Window Template and add in your view controllers instead of starting with the View template and trying to change it up.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the specified answer. I think I'm not getting something very basic here - if I set the "Main Interface" to the iPhoneViewController.xib and iPadViewController.xib the application crushes. Considering that I wish to have 1 View Controller (h and m files) for both iPhone and iPad xib, I'm not clear regarding to where I should write which code line/s to have this distinction.